# Prove that $⌊ a ⌋ + ⌊ a + 0.5 ⌋ = ⌊ 2 a ⌋ $ for every $a \in \Bbb{R} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know there are two cases here: $ ≥ 0.5$  and $ < 0.5$.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: OK, you have two cases.  That is a good start.  Now, what is $\lfloor a+0.5\rfloor$ in terms of $\lfloor a \rfloor$ in each case?  What is $\lfloor 2a \rfloor $ in each case?

Comment: In the first case ⌊ a + 0.5 ⌋ simplifies to a and in the second case it goes to a+1. I think this is right.

Comment: Yes, that is right.  That gets you the left side.  Now answer my second question to get the right side.

Comment: In the first case ⌊2⌋ would it be 2 ⌊⌋ and in the second it would be 2 ⌊⌋+1.

Comment: That is also correct.  Now combine those and you have the result you desire.